# Vertically aligning table within container div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align a table of dynamic size within a parent div. The parent container's height is set, and the inner table's height is unknown (variable). I don't think margins/relative positioning adjustments will work since the size of the table is unknown. Can this be done? Right now the code looks like:

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="board">
      <table id="evolve">...</table>
 </div> 
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
}
#board {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto; 
    width: 265px; 
    height: 222px; 
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.evolve {
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your desired css code

```
#board {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 265px; 
    height: 222px; 
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.evolve {
    border:solid 1px black;
        }
```

**UPDATE**
You will need to alter padding-left depending on wrapper width(if you set it to 100% then it will work)

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    padding-left:36%;
}
#board {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 265px; 
    height: 222px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.evolve {
    border: 1px black solid;
   }
```

As soon as i find a better solution i will update it

Comment: This works for aligning evolve, but now how do i align #board horizontally within its parent div? margin: auto no longer works

Comment: is #board also contained in a parent div?

Answer (score 0):

You can define `line-height` same as the `height` of the `DIV`. Write like this:

```
#board {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 265px;
    height: 222px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height:222px;
}
#board .evolve {
    border: 1px black solid;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    line-height:1.5;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/X4L5A/1/

Comment: this works for aligning text, but i believe line-height doesn't work for other elements like table